# Pandas : join/merge/concat two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

**Question : Count how many people has published paper(s) to more than one topic**

Exemple:

1. `Poo` has two papers which is associated to `Physics` only and since it has only one topic, it is not considered to be counted
2. `Amy` has one paper with two(2) topics (`Physics`, `Economics`), so it should be counted
3. `Baa` has two paper with distinct topic for each, so it should be counted

Example Dataframes:

```
|   | id  | name | has_published_papers                    |
|---|-----|------|-----------------------------------------|
| 0 | 100 | Amy  | pp3524172                               |
| 1 | 101 | Bla  | pp0120888,pp0343660,pp0151738,pp0120631 |
| 2 | 102 | Foo  | pp0134084,pp1262416,pp0120082,pp0117571 |
| 3 | 103 | Boo  | pp0274558,pp0108872,pp1796960,pp0117509 |
| 4 | 104 | Soo  | pp0120338,pp0993846,pp1375666,pp0407887 |
| 5 | 111 | Poo  | pp0152095,pp1234567                     |
| 6 | 112 | Baa  | pp0237474,pp0152095                     |
```

```
|    | paper_id  | name        | topics             |
|----|-----------|-------------|--------------------|
| 30 | pp3524172 | research A  | Physics, Economics |
| 40 | pp0189076 | research B  | Math, Physics      |
| 55 | pp0237474 | research C  | Education          |
| 68 | pp2729488 | research D  | Physics, Math      |
| 79 | pp0152095 | research Z  | Physics            |
| 99 | pp1234567 | research X  | Physics            |
```

**Edit**
The desired output is an `integer` representing the number of people who has published paper(s) to more than one topic

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What is the desired output ? Please, have a look at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert both DataFrames:

1. Your first DataFrame (*df*) to a DataFrame with separate row
   for each paper and the paper id as the index:

   ```
    paper = df.set_index('name').has_published_papers.str.split(',')\
        .explode().reset_index(name='id').set_index('id')
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
              name
    id            
    pp3524172  Amy
    pp0120888  Bla
    pp0343660  Bla
    pp0151738  Bla
    pp0120631  Bla
    pp0134084  Foo
    pp1262416  Foo
    pp0120082  Foo
    pp0117571  Foo
    pp0274558  Boo
    pp0108872  Boo
    pp1796960  Boo
    pp0117509  Boo
    pp0120338  Soo
    pp0993846  Soo
    pp1375666  Soo
    pp0407887  Soo
    pp0152095  Poo
    pp1234567  Poo
    pp0237474  Baa
    pp0152095  Baa
   ```
2. Your second DataFrame (*df2*) to a Series, dividing each topics row
   into separate elements and again the paper id as the index:

   ```
    topic = df2.set_index('paper_id').topics.str.split(', ').explode()
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
    paper_id
    pp3524172      Physics
    pp3524172    Economics
    pp0189076         Math
    pp0189076      Physics
    pp0237474    Education
    pp2729488      Physics
    pp2729488         Math
    pp0152095      Physics
    pp1234567      Physics
    Name: topics, dtype: object
   ```

Then:

- join both of them,
- drop duplicates (to eliminate cases where somebody has more papers
  on the same topic),
- group by *name* and count topics for each person.

The code to do it is:

```
result = paper.join(topic).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)\
    .drop_duplicates().groupby('name').count().reset_index()
```

getting:

```
  name  topics
0  Amy       2
1  Baa       2
2  Poo       1
```

And to get the true final result, retrieve rows with *topics > 1*
and get only *name* column:

```
result.query('topics > 1').name
```

The final result is:

```
0    Amy
1    Baa
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Or if you want to get plain *pythonic* list (instead of a *Series*),
add `.tolist()` to the above instruction, which this time will get:

```
['Amy', 'Baa']
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a few steps to merge those datasets.

First thing you got to do is to split and expand the `has_published_papers` column into multiple columns:

```
authors_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': [100, 101],
  'name': ['Amy', 'Bla'],
  'has_published_papers': ['pp3524172', 'pp0120888,pp0343660,pp0151738,pp0120631']
})
authors_df.has_published_papers.str.split(',', expand=True)
```

This would output

```
           0          1          2          3
0  pp3524172       None       None       None
1  pp0120888  pp0343660  pp0151738  pp0120631
```

Then you can concatenate this to your original dataframe and melt it:

```
authors_papers_df = (
    pd.concat([
        authors_df.drop(columns=['has_published_papers']),
        authors_df.has_published_papers.str.split(',', expand=True)
    ], axis=1)
    .melt(['id', 'name'], value_name='paper_id')
    .dropna(subset=['paper_id']))
```

this would output a nice dataframe ready for merging:

```
    id name variable   paper_id
0  100  Amy        0  pp3524172
1  101  Bla        0  pp0120888
3  101  Bla        1  pp0343660
5  101  Bla        2  pp0151738
7  101  Bla        3  pp0120631
```

You can do the exact same split/expand/melt pipeline to create a papers_topics dataframe.

```
papers_topics_df = (
    pd.concat([
        papers_df.drop(columns=['topics']),
        papers_df.topics.str.split(', ', expand=True)
    ], axis=1)
    .melt(['paper_id', 'name'], value_name='topic')
    .dropna(subset=['topic'])
)
```

Then you can merge then on `paper_id`.

```
authors_papers_topics_df = authors_papers_df.merge(papers_topics_df, on='paper_id')
```

Now you have a dataframe relating topics, papers and authors.

To count unique topics for each author, you can use:

```
authors_papers_topics_df.groupby('id')['topics'].nunique()
```

Saw your edit. To get number of authors that has more than one topic, use:

```
np.sum(authors_papers_topics_df.groupby('id')['topics'].nunique() > 1)
```